# $ \frac {1}{2\pi i} \int \frac {(e^z)}{z-\pi i} dz$, around a rectangle with vertices at: $(a)$ $2 \pm i$,$ -2 \pm i$ $(b)$ $-i, 2 - i, 2 + i, i.$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

How to calculate
$$ \frac {1}{2\pi i} \int \frac {(e^z)}{z-\pi i} dz,$$ around a rectangle with vertices at: *$(a)$* $2  \pm  i$, $-2  \pm  i$ $(b)$ $-i, 2 - i, 2 + i, i.$

I want to solve this math by  Cauchy integral formula. $b$ answer is $\frac{-1}{2}$. I can't find this

Comment: It's not surprising that you can't find the answer to be $-\frac{1}{2}$, because it isn't. The integrand is analytic inside and on that rectangle (the only singularity is at $z= \pi i$), so the integral is 0.

Comment: but i find the answer from book that, the answer is -1/2, i also think it will be 0. so i am confused

Comment: If the exercise really is posed as you have posed it in your question, I am afraid the answer in your book is incorrect. That happens, sadly.